# Jquery Mobile button data-mini

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, mobile

I'm a new Web-Tecnologies user.

Jquery Mobile offers **data-mini** attribute in "*button*" (elements with **data-role**="*button*").

this make the *button* more small, but yet not small as necessary to me.

The width of buttons yet are so big for my application. I realy need to put ten buttons side by side in the cellphone with small screen. (it is a requisite of system!).

So, how I can do it? buttons even more small?.

See here a exemple of code with exactly what I want: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/jroVUxgjS0

See here a screenshot of the HTML above:
http://s16.postimage.org/m9u8gn26t/Screenshot_from_2012_10_22_03_42_08.png

Comment: I think this is not a good idea to put ten buttons side by side for small screen of mobile, if you put then user did not have enough space for click the button, and it is possible that, user wants to click on button5 and click on button6. so instead of put ten buttons side by side you can put 2 or 3 button in one row.

Comment: Ten buttons of width is a requisite of this system.

In this unique system, many points indicate ten buttons of width for best use of functionality of this system.

Any alteration of this layout (ten buttons of width) will bring many problems.

Comment: for mobile you can do one thing put all buttons into one columns,one after other. User can scroll the screen and use the button. Don't know your exact requirement but just give you an idea

Answer (score 0):

Jquery mobile is designed in such a way that in each row, maximum five items can be displayed, when trying to add sixth item, it will overflow to next row. It is due to small size of mobile, as it is designed for mobile.

**EDIT:**

Yes more than five items can be displayed but it depends on device screen size, as I just run your sample on iPhone (portrait mode), and it displays 7 buttons, but in Portrait mode, it shows all 10 buttons.

[image: Output on iPhone]

Comment: more then 5 buttons can be displayed has you can see here: http://s16.postimage.org/m9u8gn26t/Screenshot_from_2012_10_22_03_42_08.png

source: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/jroVUxgjS0